# Can the U.S. self identify as a "developing" country within the WTO organization?

Tags: united-states, international

> Criticisms of the WTO by the United States and others, such as the
> European Union and Japan, fall into three major categories: the
> ability of WTO members to self-identify as “developing” countries in
> order to receive special treatment, the failure of many WTO members to
> properly notify the WTO and other WTO members of government subsidies
> in accordance with specific agreement rules, and alleged overreach by
> the Appellate Body.

https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/blogs/new-atlanticist/what-is-wrong-with-the-wto/

Can the U.S. self identify as a "developing" country within the WTO organization? Is this legally allowed, or is there a clause that would deny the U.S. to do such a thing?

Comment: Is there any evidence the US is developing?

Comment: @Studoku well that's the point, the claim is that no evidence is needed